# What does display UNCLAIMED mean?

Tags: drivers, display, video

Having added a second video card to my computer I am having difficulties getting it to work. I have connected a television to this second video card, but I don't get any signal on the television.

Searching the internet I came across this command:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

This is the result:

```
*-display
  description: Display controller
  product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE Chipset Integrated Graphics Device
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 2
  bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
  version: 01
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom
  configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
  resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:fc100000-fc17ffff
*-display UNCLAIMED
  description: VGA compatible controller
  product: 86c764/765 [Trio32/64/64V+]
  vendor: S3 Graphics Ltd.
  physical id: 8
  bus info: pci@0000:01:08.0
  version: 54
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: vga_controller
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:f4000000-f7ffffff memory:80000000-8000ffff
```

So now my question is, what does `display UNCLAIMED` mean?

Comment: see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/savage.4.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the system cannot find an appropriate driver for the device (i.e. no driver is 'claiming' it) - it *should* be supported by the S3 legacy driver, so I'm not sure why that would be the case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wasn't sure where to look to solve my issue. But this helps me put my efforts in the right direction :-)